# persisting userinfo in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing an MVC 5 Intranet site with Windows Authentication.

The site is a questionnaire with the first two pages being information and instructions, on the third page I request the user to sign a disclaimer, from then on the user can't access any other part of the questionnaire, if the disclaimer isn't signed. What I want to do is to persist the action of signing the disclaimer to the database so when the user returns I can check if he/she has signed on a previous visit in which case I omit this page. I can't quite figure out where do I persist this information to database and where do I load it, and also how do I persist this information on the session.

Any advice would be appreciated. I have seen the suggestion on this page http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx
(see number 7) but I need to save more than just one piece of information I need to save an userinfo object.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldnt do it on the database, probably better doing this on the client.

You should just be able to simply set a cookie with a flag, if true omit the page(s)/Redirect else do nothing.

I guess the next question is 'do you need to know if a specific user has read the disclaimer?', in which case then store in the database as well for future reference. Depends if this flag is useful going forward or just to control the mecahanism.

Hope that helps.